# how to store a calculation from an input to memory, input repeats, first calculation from input is added to second calculation from input and so on?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, do-while

I need some help with a program I'm trying to make using Java.

I'm currently a freshman in Information Technology and for finals, we have to do an electrical billing program of some sort I've already done some code but it won't work the way I want it to. Can anyone help me fix it?

flow of program:
1)user inputs multiple numbers to be calculated
2)program calculates it
3)the result of the calculation from step 2 is stored somewhere
4)program asks user if they want to input again
5)if user chooses input again the process repeats from step 1 to 2 and is added to the first calculation and so on and so forth

```
static Scanner console = new Scanner (System.in);
Double loopFor=0.0;
Double w,h,kwh,t;


System.out.print("\nHello and welcome to Pikabill. The electricity bill estimate calculator.");
while(true) {
do {
System.out.print("\nEnter what is being asked. You might have to refer to labels on your appliances");
    System.out.print("\nWATTAGE (W): ");
    w=console.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("\nUSAGE (in HOURS): ");
    h=console.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("\nELECTRICITY RATE (kWh): ");
    kwh=console.nextDouble();

    t=(w*h)/1000*kwh;

System.out.print("\nCOST: " + t);
loopFor += t;

System.out.print("\nWould you like to continue? YES [y] No [n]");
String c= console.nextLine();

 if(c.equalsIgnoreCase("n")){ 
      break;

}

}
while (loopFor !=0);
}
}
```

}

somehow, when I run this the calculation works fine, but when it comes to displaying the t (the calculation), it shows the "do you want to continue" just fine but the "Hello and welcome to Pikabill...." shows on the next line even though i havent pressed y. It also doesn't add the previous calculations to the newer ones as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This piece of code will work.
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ElectricalBillingProgram
{

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    Double loopFor = 0.0;
    Double w, h, kwh, t;
    for (int i = 0;; i++)
    {
        System.out.print("\nEnter what is being asked. You might have to refer to labels on your appliances");
        System.out.print("\nWATTAGE (W): ");
        w = console.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("\nUSAGE (in HOURS): ");
        h = console.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("\nELECTRICITY RATE (kWh): ");
        kwh = console.nextDouble();

        t = (w * h) / 1000 * kwh;

        System.out.print("\nCOST: " + t);
        loopFor += t;

        System.out.print("\nWould you like to continue? YES [y] No [n]");
        String c = console.next();

        if (c.equalsIgnoreCase("n"))
        {
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

}

Observations from your code:
Never mixup "while" and "doWhile", if it confuses you, use "for" loop.
use console.next() instead of console.nextLine().
Happy learning!

Answer (score 0):

This should be your code -

```
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    Double loopFor = 0.0;
    Double w, h, kwh, t;

    System.out.println("Hello and welcome to Pikabill. The electricity bill estimate calculator.");
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Enter what is being asked. You might have to refer to labels on your appliances");
        System.out.println("WATTAGE (W): ");
        w = console.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("USAGE (in HOURS): ");
        h = console.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("ELECTRICITY RATE (kWh): ");
        kwh = console.nextDouble();

        t = (w * h) / 1000 * kwh;

        loopFor += t;
        System.out.println("COST:\t" + t);
        System.out.println("loopFor:\t" + loopFor);

        System.out.println("Would you like to continue? YES [y] No [n]");
        String c = console.next();

        if (c.equals("n")) {
            break;
        }
    }
```